# Start a process and allow it to use connected network drives

Tags: powershell, process, network-drive

I am trying to back up a network share to an USB drive, while archiving the data. To do this, I'm calling 7-zip archiver (actually it doesn't matter which archiver I use) like this:

```
new-psdrive -name O -psprovider filesystem -root '\\kapital-dc01\disk_o'  -credential $cred 
$arclog=(. 'c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe' a -bb1 -bd -bse1 -mmt6 -r -v1200m "f:\disk_o\disk_o-$timestamp.7z" 'o:\')
```

7-zip, however, reports a "file not found" error while trying to get data from O:. In Powershell I am able to `dir o:\` without any problem. This script is run as a job via Task Manager as `SYSTEM` account. What should I use to start 7-zip with access to attached network drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `-Persist` switch for `New-PSDrive` to make the drive available for the windows session and not just the PowerShell session.

> You can use the Persist parameter of New-PSDrive to create Windows
>   mapped network drives. Unlike temporary Windows PowerShell drives,
>   Windows mapped network drives are not session-specific. They are saved
>   in Windows and they can be managed by using standard Windows tools,
>   such as File Explorer and Net Use.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)

Comment: Will this setting allow closing the network connection after script ends, or should I need to manually disconnect those drives?

Comment: Disconnect it at the end with `Remove-PSDrive`

Comment: Thanks. I used `Register-EngineEvent` with `Remove-PSDrive` calls to remove connections in case script would fail, and it originally has numerous points of failure.